# Tomcat: HikariCP issue when deploying two applications with DB connection

Tags: java, tomcat7, hikaricp

I am trying to deploye two WAR files (app1.war and app2.war) on the same tomcat7 instance. I am getting this error :

```
Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-0)] with key
  'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
  com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
```

I don't have this error if I have only one application deployed on tomcat.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 11):

In Spring Boot, a JMX Bean is loaded at runtime and it scans your application. If two data sources are found, it's going to throw `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException`. This can be resolved by defining the default JMX domain name in your application.properties file as follows:

```
spring.jmx.default-domain=app_name
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: There is a discussion ongoing regarding this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5911 


Hope, Spring devs fix this.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Boot you can change the name of the Hikari data source pool via application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=MyDataPoolName
```

or application.yml respectivly:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      pool-name: MyDataPoolName
```

Then Tomcat can load both applications and the name conflict is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Give your data sources unique names.  For example, if you have separate schemas for storing user and product data, you could name your data sources `userDS` and `productDS`, respectively.

### Programmatic configuration

---

```
HikariDataSource userDS = new HikariDataSource();
userDS.setPoolName("userDS");
// Set other data source properties.

HikariDataSource productDS = new HikariDataSource();
productDS.setPoolName("productDS");
// Set other data source properties.
```

### Spring configuration

---

```
<bean id="userDS" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="poolName" value="userDS"/>
  ...
</bean>

<bean id="productDS" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="poolName" value="productDS"/>
  ...
</bean>
```

Comment: How to do this in spring boot application?

Comment: Use the programmatic (Java) configuration.

Comment: @Manu See my answer to this question