# Jhipster : deploying two application on one single tomcat instance

Tags: jhipster

Is it possible to deploy two jhipster apps on a single instance of tomcat7?
I am getting this problem while deploying the two wars :

> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup
>   failed org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException:
>   Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-0)] with key
>   'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
>   com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource   at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:613)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:538)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:420)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:782)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117)
>   [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108)
>   [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68)
>   [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
>   [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
>   [tomcat-catalina-7.0.55.jar:7.0.55]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [tomcat-catalina-7.0.55.jar:7.0.55]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>   [tomcat-catalina-7.0.55.jar:7.0.55]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>   [tomcat-catalina-7.0.55.jar:7.0.55]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>   [tomcat-catalina-7.0.55.jar:7.0.55]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
>   [tomcat-catalina-7.0.55.jar:7.0.55]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
>   [tomcat-catalina-7.0.55.jar:7.0.55]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
>   Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
>   com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource   at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:658)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:603)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]     ... 24 common
>   frames omitted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat7 : hikari issue when deploying two applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284984/tomcat7-hikari-issue-when-deploying-two-applications)

Comment: You have already asked this question [once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284984/tomcat7-hikari-issue-when-deploying-two-applications).  Instead of asking the same question multiple times, provide the right level of detail in a single question and close all others.

Comment: I have given you pointers to solving this in an answer to your earlier question.  You will have to look at the class [DatabaseConfiguration](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.java) for giving a unique name to your HikariCP datasource.