# ested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, hikaricp

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/internals]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-3)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.lambda$registerBeans$2(MBeanExporter.java:551)
        at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:551)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:434)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
        at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:137)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:671)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
        ... 43 more
```

We use that configuration, not anything about `hikari`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.xx.0.160:1433;databaseName=DEV_DB_Ux;
```

There are 2 modules of spring boot those use same data source.

So, because of that it says this but on local there is no problem.

One uses 8080, one uses 8090 ports.

I got this error on tomcat but I dont use `hikari` anywhere.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [override the default RegistrationPolicy](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/342) (since Spring Boot 2.1.3)

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableMBeanExport(registration = RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING)
> public class MXBeansConfig {
> }
> ```

Comment: I dont have that class

Comment: @CanerAydın what's your Spring Boot version? also check other suggestions in link

Comment: 2.1.5.RELEASE version

Comment: @CanerAydın what class you are missing? you can add it

Comment: i dont have any configuration for EnableMBeanExport. We dont have mbean :(

Comment: @CanerAydın see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284984/tomcat-hikaricp-issue-when-deploying-two-applications-with-db-connection